# What I Understand & Do Not Understand About This Projective Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am thinking through a specific case to try and fix some ideas.

Suppose that $ S = \frac{k[x,y,z]}{(x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2})}, $ and $ S $ is graded in the natural way. One point of $ \text{Proj}(S) $ which is not closed is the generic point $ (0) $ because $ \overline{(0)} = \text{Proj}(S). $ Are there any other non-closed points?

I acknowledge that the closed points of $ \text{Proj}(S) $ correspond to points of $ V(x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}), $ and in spite of knowing that maximal ideals classically correspond to points, I feel that scheme-theoretically, I don't truly see why.

As to the homogeneous distinguished open sets:

$ D_{+}(z) = \text{Spec}\Big[S \Big[\frac{1}{z}\Big]\Big]_{0} = \text{Spec}\frac{k[\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}]}{\Big(\frac{x^2}{z^2} + \frac{y^2}{z^2} -1 \Big)}. $

So the $ D_{+}(f) $ is a conic for $ f \in S_{+}, $ and in particular, when $ \text{deg}(f) = 1. $

Comment: I assume $k$ is a field; are there more assumptions on $k$? Is $\operatorname{char}k=0$ or is $k$ algebraically closed? Note that if $\operatorname{char}k=2$ then $(0)$ is not prime.

Comment: $ k $ is algebraically closed and $ \text{char}(k) = 0. $

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that the zero ideal of $S$ in not prime if $\operatorname{char}k=2$, as then
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=(x+y+z)^2.$$
If $\operatorname{char}k\neq2$ then it *is* prime, which I won't verify here (it isn't hard to do so though).

A non-closed point of $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is a non-maximal homogeneous prime ideal of $S$ that doesn't contain the irrelevant ideal $(x,y,z)\subset S$. Because $S/(x,y,z)\cong k$ is a field, there are no non-maximal prime ideals containing the irrelevant ideal. So you are looking for a homogeneous prime ideal of $S$ that isn't maximal.

One example is the ideal $I=(x,y-z)$, which contains $(x^2+y^2-z^2)$ because
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=x\cdot x+(y+z)\cdot(y-z).$$
It is a prime ideal because
$$S/I=(k[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2-z^2))/(x,y-z)\cong k[x,y,z]/(x,y-z)\cong k[t],$$
is a domain, and $I$ is non-maximal because $k[t]$ is not a field.

Can you find more examples? And something other than the now obvious $I'=(y,x-z)$?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but $(x,y-z)$ corresponds to the point $[0:1:1]$, which is closed. The scheme $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is irreducible of dimension one (as $\operatorname{char} k \neq 2$) and thus should not have any nonclosed points besides the unique generic point already found by the asker.